# How to align all elements on same axis

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to align all my elements on the same axis. The element can be anything: input, dropdown, button, etc. I am trying to accomplish this using only CSS. I know we can use MUI Stack component to align them but I only want to do it via CSS. The first image below shows an example of how it currently looks, which you can see is unaligned. The second image is the expected alignment that I want. Not sure how to proceed to make it aligned?

[image: It is not aligned]

[image: It is aligned]

```
import * as React from "react";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

export default function BasicButtons() {
  return (
    <span>
      <TextField id="standard-basic" label="Standard" variant="standard" />
      <Button variant="contained">Contained</Button>
      <Button variant="outlined">Outlined</Button>
    </span>
  );
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using a flexbox in css.

Add this to your css stylesheet:

```
/* Add this CSS to your stylesheet */
.container {
display: flex;
align-items: center; /* This aligns the items vertically in the center */
justify-content: start; /* This aligns the items to the start of the container horizontally */
gap: 10px; /* This adds some space between the items */
}
```

Then, wrap your elements with a div or another container element that uses this class:

```
import * as React from "react";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

export default function BasicButtons() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <TextField id="standard-basic" label="Standard" variant="standard" />
      <Button variant="contained">Contained</Button>
      <Button variant="outlined">Outlined</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It is better with your suggestion but it still not aligned on the same axis. The buttons are slightly off above the axis of the text field.

Comment: I'm sorry, not sure how to change it then